# Перенаправление возможных переменных в .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

помогите перенаправить

```
http://subdomain.example.com/page/subpage
```

на

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?subdomain=subdomain&page=page&subpage=subpage
```

с помощью htaccess. Некоторые переменные могут не быть указаны (субдомен без страниц, или страницы/подстраницы без субдомена)

Answer (score 0):

Как то так:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./адрес/$1
```